# ksh batch processing

Tags: transactions, ksh, batch-processing

I have a shell script that reads the user id's line by line from a file and inserts records into the database. However insertion process is slow and I want to optimize by taking in batches. I cannot use entire file as one batch as the transaction size exceeds the proprietary limits. Here is the script:

```
for user in `cat $userlist`
do 
echo "processing user $user"
{
    echo "begin"
        i=1
        while [[ $i -le 30 ]] ; do
        echo "insert into usertab values ($user,-1,\"\",-1)" 
        i=$(expr $i + 1)
        done
        echo "commit"
} | propSql userDb -
done
```

Begin and commit are standard key words for this db. Here, instead of processing one user at a time, I want to process 10 users at a time. Can some one suggest the change needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows a way to accumulate users 10 at a time. You will need to modify it to suit the way you need the data to look for the `insert` statement. I left the inner loop in place, but changed it to a `for` loop since that makes all the control happen in one place. You may not need that loop though.

```
process () {
   # Somewhere in here you'll use the value of "$@"
   echo "begin"
        # you may not need this loop any more
        for ((i=1; i<30; i++))
        do
            echo "insert into usertab values ($user,-1,\"\",-1)" 
        done
    echo "commit"
}

j=0
while read -r user
do 
    echo "processing user $user"
    if ! (( j++ % 10 ))    # every tenth user, do a database operation
    then
        process "$accum" | propSql userDb -
        accum=""
    fi
    accum+=" $user"    # accumulate user names
done < "$userlist"
process "$accum" | propSql userDb -    # one more time to get the remainder
```

Note that this is written using ksh93 syntax. If you're using another version, you'll need to make some modifications.